# Creating an index column for Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I have a table of member IDs and transactions in Power BI, I would like to create an index column for it, any suggestions?

Regards

Comment: If your table contains a column of (presumably unique) IDs, why do you need to add an extra index column? It might help to expand your question with sample data and desired results. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 28):

My preferred method is to use PowerQuery (Power BI's Query Editor). Here's how:

- Click the "Home" tab in Power BI and then click the "Edit Queries" button.
- Then, under "Queries" on the left side of the screen, click on the name of
  the table you want to add the index to.
- Then click on the "Add Column" tab and then click the "Index Column"
  button. (If you click the down arrow beside the Index Column button,
  you can decide what number to start the index with.)

  [image]
- Then click "File" and "Close & Apply".

Comment: I have Version: 2.87.684.0 64-bit (November 2020) and I don't see those options. did they move them? google doesn't seem to be helping me find the answer @marc pincince

Comment: No @Raymond. They are still there. I just looked, and I have the same version as you. Make sure you click the down-arrow to the right of "Index Column," or you won't see "From 0," "From 1," and "Custom...."