# powerbi starting index at "0" or "1"?

Tags: indexing, powerbi

the post here

[Creating an index column for Power Bi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715963/creating-an-index-column-for-power-bi)

suggests starting at "1". I don't know why MS would offer a choice, as if it's unique... it shouldn't matter. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's purely a choice by the user for what's the easiest to understand. Most programming languages will index starting from 0, and only some from 1. Most non-programmers will probably prefer indexing from 1.

But I don't think the value has any impact on actual behavior of the indexing.