# Calculate time gaps between two different columns

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I’m looking to calculate the time gap between a previous interview end time, with the next interviews start time. Referring to the image attached, as an example, I would like to calculate L72-M71 to get 5 minutes but for all values of L[n]-M[n-1]. I can easily do this in Excel, however, I am having difficulty with figuring out how to do this in Power BI.

If anyone could provide insight, that would be much appreciated!

My example table:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the same data sample as text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Time GAP = 
var totsecs = DATEDIFF(timeTest[ST];timeTest[ET];SECOND)
var minutes = FLOOR(totsecs/60;1)
return TIME(FLOOR(minutes/60;1);MOD(minutes;60);MOD(totsecs;60))
```

You need to ensure the column is of type 'time', it will convert by default to DateTime

Answer (score 0):

@Aldert has it almost right, but it's missing the reference to the previous row.

In order for that to work, you should have some index-field in the dataset, which you could add after the data has been loaded to Power BI: [Creating an index column for Power Bi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715963/creating-an-index-column-for-power-bi)

Then you can use dax EARLIER-function to get the Interview End Time from previous row and calculate Time GAP, something like this:

```
Time GAP = 
var prevEt = CALCULATE(MAX([Interview End Time]);ALL(Table1); Table1[Index]+1=EARLIER(Table1[Index]))
var totsecs = DATEDIFF(prevEt;Table1[Interview Start Time];SECOND)
var minutes = FLOOR(totsecs/60;1)
return TIME(FLOOR(minutes/60;1);MOD(minutes;60);MOD(totsecs;60))
```

Update:
This calculated column formula considers the interviewer and date as well (it's not pretty, I'm sure there's a better way of doing this):

```
enter code hereTime GAP = 
var curInterviewer = [Interviewid] // the column of interviewer id
var curDate = [Date] // the column of interview date
var prevEt = CALCULATE(MAX([Interview End Time]);ALL(Table1) ;FILTER(Table1;[InterviewId] = curInterviewer); FILTER(Table1;[Date] = curDate); Table1[Index]+1=EARLIER(Table1[Index]))
var totsecs = DATEDIFF(prevEt;Table1[Interview Start Time];SECOND)
var minutes = FLOOR(totsecs/60;1)
return TIME(FLOOR(minutes/60;1);MOD(minutes;60);MOD(totsecs;60))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I've attempted to do this but forgot to mention that I need to account for days and individual. Each of these interviews need to be categorized by date and customer service agent. For instance, I wouldn't want someone to be penalized for an interview time gap that was calculated across two different days or two different customer service agents. How do you think I should go about resolving this as I have no clue.

Comment: Hi @JessicaKong  I added updated vesrion of the formula to my answer