# How to delete rows from the table in power query?

Tags: powerbi

I have a table

| sub_id | amount | status | stateid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15000 | 2 | true |
| 1 | 15000 | 4 | true |
| 1 | 19000 | 2 | true |

There is wrong data in the table. I need to delete the 3rd row. Irrespective of position in the table.

I tried the below query in the advanced editor

```
Table.SelectRows(#"ABC", each (sub_id=1 and amount=19000) = 0)
```

It returns zero rows

Give me some insight

Answer (score 2):

### Updated

I was overthinking this on my first try. This is much simpler, just use:

```
Table.RemoveRows(yourtableName, zrowBasedRow, 1)
```

- `yourtableName` would be the previous variable
- `zrowBasedRow` would be the row number with `0` being the start (so *third* would be 2).

### Original Answer

Add [an index column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715963/creating-an-index-column-for-power-bi), then filter on value not equal to 3 (assuming you make using base 1 for index column), then remove index column.

So using advanced editor...

```
let
    Source = whatever....,
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),

    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Index] <> 3),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

So sample start...

[image]

Added index, base 1

[image]

Then filtered...

[image]

And remove index column.

Answer (score 0):

Change `0` to `false`.

```
Table.SelectRows(#"ABC", each (sub_id = 1 and amount = 19000) = false)
```

Or you can use `not`.

```
Table.SelectRows(#"ABC", each not (sub_id = 1 and amount = 19000))
```